# ffmpeg - Overlay video on top of the image

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

[image]

Hello there! I am trying to add background image to my video but for some reason is doesn't work. I try different option with ffmpeg and none of them worked for me, sometimes i have image over my video but never video over my image.

```
def resizeVideo(video_path):

            video_duration = 0

            clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
            if clip.duration < 25 or video_duration < 600:

                status = check_for_copyright.music_cheker(video_path)
                almost_editor = f'{video_path.replace(".mp4","")}_almost.mp4'
                final_video = f'{video_path.replace(".mp4","")}_final.mp4'
                if status:
                    
                    os.system(f"ffmpeg -i .\\{video_path}  -vf \"scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:\"  {almost_editor}")

                    os.system(f"ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.jpg  -i .\\{almost_editor}  -filter_complex \"overlay=0:0:shortest=1\" {final_video}")
                    video_duration += clip.duration
                else:
                    pass
            else:

                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[fg];[1][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4
```